# How to restrict users from enabling add on in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome

Please let me is there any possibility to  restrict system users from  installing addon in chrome browser

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/2657289?hl=en and https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3463947?hl=en  Chrome is a 3rd party app so I would suggest following the support site for chrome.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but most of the users doesnt hold a google account , it  wont  work for us